# Writing hebrew to mySql using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, hebrew

I have a small Java method that inserts short messages to a MySQL Database.
the table's default Collation is utf8_unicode_ci and the java code is:

```
private void insertMessageToDataBase(String lRoom, String lChatusername,
            String lMessage) {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/embeddedChat?" +
                "user=site_access&password=XXXXXXX");
            addMessageToDataBase = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `" + lRoom + "` (username, message, action)" +
                    " VALUES (?,?,'message');");
            addMessageToDataBase.setString(1, lChatusername);
            addMessageToDataBase.setString(2, lMessage);
            addMessageToDataBase.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the problem is that when lMessage is in hebrew the result is a string of '??????'

BTW:
I don't know if it helps but there is also a PHP script that sometimes write to another similar table in this database and it works fine.

Comment: Make sure that your tables are set up to accept hebrew (utf-8 is probably the safest/easiest choice), then make sure your entire pipeline is set for utf-8 as well: scripts, input systems, database link (even if the table is utf, the link might not be).

Comment: @MarcB what do you mean by link? is this the jdbc connector? the input system is. I know this because it also sends the string forward to other methods that receive it fine. and the only script there is, is the one I've pasted above? can you be more specific about the link part? I'm not sure I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set UTF-8 in your code. See this;

```
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/embeddedChat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Marc B for helping me find out what went wrong. This will be just a summery for any future developer who may fall upon a similar issue.

So, from the comment by Marc (above on my question) I understood I needed to check the link. I did not know how to do so but I did a brief google search and came upon this page: http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/tomcat-java-mysql-jdbc-and-unicode

actually all I needed to do was add the following line to the connection string: *&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8*

this is how my **working** code looks now:

```
    private void insertMessageToDataBase(String lRoom, String lChatusername,
            String lMessage) {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/embeddedChat?" +
                "user=site_access&password=XXXXXXXX&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
            addMessageToDataBase = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `" + lRoom + "` (username, message, action)" +
                    " VALUES (?,?,'message');");
            addMessageToDataBase.setString(1, lChatusername);
            addMessageToDataBase.setString(2, lMessage);
            addMessageToDataBase.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It's a mess of course and needs some clean up, but this is a ***working*** code.

Thank you Marc B