# Setting the mysql collation correctly

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert to my table hebrew values but the result is always "??????".
Which collation should I use?I tried to use hebrew_bin and hebrew_general_ci and the result was the same.
The reason I used the Java tag is that my code is written in java and as far as I know in web development you have to specify the collation in the web scripts also.
So maybe I have to do that in the java code also?

**EDIT**
Here is the code:

```
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:port/";
private String dbName = "dbname";
private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String userName = "user"; 
private String password = "password";
```

....

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO locations(location) VALUES (?)");
                    stmt.setString(1, "hebrew sentence");
                    stmt.execute();
```

Now how do I change my code into the example you showed?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Which charset is the database using?

Comment: hmm I couldn't find a field called charset but the collation is: utf8_general_ci

Comment: How do you know the result is '?????'. This is a unicode issue and unicode issues come on two variants: storing it badly and displaying it badly. Perhaps the problem is in displaying it.

Comment: I looked in the phpmyadmin

Comment: Show your code who add values to mysql databse.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11980491/1134705

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Answer (score 2):

As per a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976074/writing-hebrew-to-mysql-using-java) you might try this:

---

Posted by: [Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11980491/1134705):

Set UTF-8 in your code. See the following:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/embeddedChat?" +
            "user=site_access&password=XXXXXXXX&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
```

---

Personalized to your connection of course

See the following:

[Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC DriverManager Interface](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

[JDBC Basics - Establishing a Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

Comment: @ImriPersiado Fixed, showing username and password implementation.

Comment: That's confusing, I need to send 3 parameters.. I see only 1. url,username,password

Comment: ??? Please elaborate? In my above answer I have `getConnection(url, username, password, unicode boolean, character encoding)`. Show me what you need to send.

Comment: I have 4 variables, url,dbname, username and password and I pass them in the getConnection method. Your answer use just 1 long String parameter that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @ImriPersiado On the SO question I have linked above, check out the OP's resolution answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11985858/1134705 . Also without seeing exactly what and how you are passing, it is hard to help. In your OP add your `getConnection()` and anything else you think is necessary for me to help.

Comment: In your query you don't specift a db

Comment: Please give me more code and then I can help further, post in your OP, not comments. I can only make assumptions without seeing anything.

Answer (score -2):

```
set the table you needed to utf8 and all the rows in it to
utf8 the added this to the connection script:mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

This will help you I guess

Comment: How can I do that: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); in java?

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: isn't deprecated now, will be deprecated.

Comment: I think this answer is for PHP, but the question is for Java