# MySQL - Hebrew characters become question marks in DB

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, http

I have DB which all of its columns are set to be "hebrew_general_ci".

When I try to manually insert hebrew values to my DB, or through Postman, I can see that the values at the DB are indeed in hebrew.

But, When I try to insert the values from my app (android app - coded in java), the values become question marks - ????

I tried to code my text to UTF-8 at the app itself but it didn't work.

here is the code which suppose to do this:

```
private String POST(String url, String jsonParamsAsString) {
        String result = "";
        String fixedUrl = url.replace(" ","%20");
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(fixedUrl);
            byte  ptext[] = jsonParamsAsString.getBytes();
            jsonParamsAsString = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonParamsAsString);
            input.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8" );
            //input.setContentType("application/json");
            postRequest.setEntity(input);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            result = convertInputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            /*byte  ptext[] = result.getBytes();
            result = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your encoding for the database as utf8 / utf8_general_ci or utf8mb4 / utf8mb4_general_ci if you are running latest version of MySQL & need to handle emoji. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) is the documentation. Basically, you don't need to set your table to a specific char set for a particular language. I've used the above settings and it handles Arabic, Russian, Chinese, English, etc. out of the box, it is language agnostic and just works. Good luck.

Edit: You also need to make sure your query connection has the following two parameters: `useUnicode=yes` and `characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Comment: Is the query connection you meant is that I put above?

Comment: @Binyamina no you need to find where your java database connector is, something like this:  `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/embeddedChat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8");`

Comment: @Binyamina also please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976074/writing-hebrew-to-mysql-using-java) as in the answers section they appear to solve your issue exactly.

Comment: i put this URL: public  static  final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/<name of db>?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"; and it doesn't work...